# how to set background color of range in TTTAtributedLabel

Tags: tttattributedlabel

Can't figure out how to set the background color of a range to make it look like a highlighter

The yellow color below does not show up as the background color

```
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,(id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName, (id) NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil];
NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleNone], [UIColor yellowColor], nil];
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

self.madLibLabel.linkAttributes = linkAttributes;


[self.madLibLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"what://"] withRange:[self.madLibLabel.text rangeOfString:@"WHAT"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName` key instead `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,(id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName, (id) kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName, nil];
NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleNone], [UIColor yellowColor], nil];
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

self.madLibLabel.linkAttributes = linkAttributes;


[self.madLibLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"what://"] withRange:[self.madLibLabel.text rangeOfString:@"WHAT"]];
```